# Android MotionLayout with app bundle not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-app-bundle, android-motionlayout

I have simple [project](https://github.com/Anrimian/MotionLayoutWithAppBundleExample) with MotionLayout. There is a seek bar that changes the state of MotionLayout using the setProgress() method.

When I deploy default APK, all works, child view moves. If I use "APK from app bundle" deploy, MotionLayout not works(child view don't moves), like it missed layoutDescription.

[image]

Example project [here](https://github.com/Anrimian/MotionLayoutWithAppBundleExample).

MotionLayout version:

```
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

Comment: What happens when you install the apk? Does it crash and do you get any logs?

Comment: When i install "default apk", all works fine. When i deploy app bundle to google play and install app - motion layout not works. I reproduced this problem in this project, just switch deploy in "installation options" to "APK from app bundle".

Comment: if you are using proguard then use -keep class for MotionLayoutUtils for detail https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/dexguard

Comment: I have the same problem if you generate the APK instead of the .aab. It should run normally.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Does it crash? Does it display something unexpected? Can you be more specific? Can you look at the logcat if there's any errors about your app?

Comment: I updated my question and simplify example project. I did not observe something weird in logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will should be fixed in `ConstraintLayout` alpha 3: https://twitter.com/johnhoford/status/1061001715481079808

Comment: It seems that in recent versions of gradle(3.5.0) this has been fixed and the issue has been resolved.